# java: create an objects from two constructors

Tags: java, object, constructor

This is an example from **"SCJP" *by Kathy Sierra***: Chapter 2 - Object Orientation

```
class X { void do1() {} }

class Y extends X { void do2() {} }

class Chrome {

     public static void main (String args[]) {
         X x1 = new X();
         X x2 = new Y(); //***** question is regarding this line
         Y y1 = new Y();
         ((Y)x2).do2();
     }
}
```

Is it legal to create an object using two constructors?  And what type of object is `x2`: `X` or `Y`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Those are NOT two constructors**

```
 X x2 = new Y();
```

- `X` is Type of variable
- `x2` is reference variable which can refer to `X` and hence any subclass of `X`, in this case, it can refer to `Y`.
- `new Y()` actually creates the object of class `Y` in the memory and the variable `x` refer to the object.

This is possible because `Y` extends `X` hence it passes `IS-A` test. This is example of polymorphism. A super type is referring to object of subtype.

- At compile time, `x2` reference variable will be of type `X`
- At runtime, `x2` will refer to a subclass object i.e. of type `Y`.

So if there is a method in class `X` that is overridden by  a method in class `Y`, the method of class `Y` will get called because the object is of type `Y`.

Consider these classes.

```
public class X {

    public void someMethod(){
        System.out.println("we are in class X method");
    }
}
```

and another class

```
public class Y extends X {

    public void someMethod(){
        System.out.println("we are in class Y method ");
    }


    public static void main(String [] args){
        X x = new X();
        X x2 = new Y();
        Y y = new Y();

        x.someMethod();
        x2.someMethod();
        y.someMethod();
    }

}
```

This outputs

```
we are in class X method
we are in class Y method 
we are in class Y method
```

The explanation is :

- The statement `X x = new X();` creates object of `X` with reference of `X` so calls `someMethod` of class `X`.
- The statement `X x2 = new Y();` creates a reference variable of `X` but the object of class `Y` so the overriding method of class `Y` is called because overridden methods have dynamic binding. and which overridden method to call is dependent on the object type.
- For the statement `Y y = new Y()`, same  explanation as of point 1.

Comment: so i guess only class Y methods can be applied on x2?

Comment: If the reference variable is of type `X` then the compiler thinks that it will be used to call class `X` methods, but those methods are called dependending on the object. So at runtime, Y class method gets called.

Answer (score 1):

`x2` has a compile-time type of `X` but a runtime type of `Y`. What this is means, is that when the compiler needs to reason about `x2` it will assume that `x2` is an `X`. But at runtime, the behavior of `x2` will be that of a `Y`.

So let's explain this a little more verbosely. This is *not* legal:

```
x2.do2();
```

This is because the compiler thinks that `x2` is an `X` and `X` doesn't have a method named `do2`, only `Y` does. The compiler doesn't know that `x2` is a `Y`, it only know the compile-time type of `x2` is an `X`.

This, however, would be legal, and will *not* cause a runtime exception:

```
((Y)x2).do2();
```

We're telling the compiler, look, I know more than you about `x2`; I know that it's a `Y`, so just emit instructions that invoke `Y.do2` with `x2` as the receiver.

Additionally, let's assume we had a method that accepts `Y`s:

```
void M(Y y) { }
```

Then this would *not* be legal:

```
M(x2);
```

Again, this is because the compiler thinks that `x2` is a `X`, not all `X`s are `Y`s, so it has to reject the method invocation.

This, however, would be legal, and will *not* cause a runtime exception:

```
M((Y)x2);
```

Again, we're telling the compiler, look, I know more than you know about `x2`; I know that it's a `Y`, so just trust me, and invoke that method as if `x2` were a `Y`.

Let's further assume we have a method defined in `X` and overridden in `Y`:

```
class X {
    void do1() {}
    void N() { System.out.println("X");
}

class Y extends X { void do2() {} 
    @Override
    void N() { System.out.println("Y");
}
```

Now if we say:

```
x2.N();
```

we will see *`Y`* printed to the console. This is because the *runtime* type of `x2` is `Y`.

All of this is *part* of what people mean when they speak of [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming).

> Is it legal to create an object using two constructors.

There are *not* two constructors in this statement:

```
X x2 = new Y();
```

There is exactly one constructor. The left hand side is a variable declaration. It's declaring a variable named `x2` of type `X`. The right hand side is a constructor invocation. We are invoking the public parameterless constructor of `Y`; this will create a new instance of `Y`. The entire statement is an assignment statement. We are assigning the result of the right hand side to the variable on the left hand side. The assignment is legal because all `Y`s are *polymorphically* also `X`s, since `Y extends X`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is legal and its not two constructors, just different reference types.

The instance is of `Y` type but the reference is of `X` type. So you won't be able to call methods of `Y` on that.

`new Y()` creates new instance of Y aka **Runtime** type

`X x2 = new Y();` assigns it to reference of type X (aka **Compile time type**) which can hold Y, as X is superclass of Y

To test:

```
if(x2 instanceof Y){
   System.out.println("Instance is of Y");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`x2` is really a `Y` object at run-time.  At compile-time, `x2` will be treated like an `X` object.

This is really useful for polymorphism, where at compile-time, you might not really know what type of object you will be dealing with, but you know you will be dealing with objects that inherit from `X`.

Answer (score 0):

You can always assign a derived class to a variable of a type from the class hierarchy.

```
X x = new Y();  // is valid.
Y y = x;   // is not valid without a cast, even though x is actually of class Y
```

Therefore it is valid to assign an object of Y to a variable of type X but not the other way around.

If you call functions on X and they are overriden in Y, then they will be called as well. However, if Y introduces new functions you can not call them from X of course.

Answer (score 0):

Its legal to create an object using a constructor which use another constructor.

Comment: are you sure what you are saying?